# C# word file not opening

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to read a text from word file then replace some text in it and then save it with another name in the same format in c#. But when I am opening the generated document its not opening with ms word,but its opening with notepad++. I want the word file.Whats the problem in the code?
Thanks in advance.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/CustomerDocument/SampleNDA4.docx");


        TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor(path);
        string text = extractor.ExtractText();

        //System.IO.File.Create(path).Close();
        text = text.Replace("<var_Date>", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"));

        //System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/CustomerDocument/GeneratedNDA3.docx"));

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/CustomerDocument/GeneratedNDA3.docx"), text);
```

Comment: Word documents are not text.  You can't do that.

Comment: try to use openxml library

Comment: Word documents are not text. Using `WriteAllText` to create one is not going to work. You need to use something like the Office Object Model: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xatbkd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You can't do that unless you have set the default app as notepad++ for doc(x) files.

Comment: can you please provide a way by which I can read word file,replace some text in it and save it in another word file

Comment: change the word file's extension to .xml, then doublclick in VS and you will understand ;-)

Comment: @abdulrafay this might be a good starting point [How to: Open and add text to a word processing document (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478255.aspx)

Comment: I meant *.zip not *.xml :-(

Comment: Do something like this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` library to save documents as a Word file. Please check if below code works for you:

```
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

            //Start Word and create a new document.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;
            oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = false;
            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            oDoc.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
            oDoc.Content.Text = "String text;

            object filename = @"c:\temp1.docx";
            oDoc.SaveAs2(ref filename);
            oDoc.Close(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            oDoc = null;
            oWord.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            oWord = null;
```

Note: MS Word should be installed on the server where this code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below options based on your requirements. All the options have a nuget package to be installed on the project.

1. Using [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.aspx)

   ```
   using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\Git\source.docx", true))
   {
      foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in myDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>())
      {
          string innerText = objParagraph.InnerText;

          string modifiedString = innerText.Replace("<var_Date>", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"));

          if (modifiedString != innerText)
          {
              Run newRun = new Run();
              newRun.AppendChild(new Text(modifiedString));
              objParagraph.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
              objParagraph.AppendChild(newRun);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Using Office Interop, but will require MSOffice installed on server.

   ```
      Application app = new Application();
      Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"C:\Git\source.docx");

      foreach (Paragraph objParagraph in doc.Paragraphs)
      {
          objParagraph.Range.Text = objParagraph.Range.Text.Trim().Replace("<var_Date>", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy")) + "\r\n";
      }

      doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\Git\finalFile.docx");
      doc.Close();
      app.Quit();
   ```

   - Will require MSOffice installed on server
   - Its a bit slow , so not suitable for high usage scenarios.
3. Using [Aspose.Words](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/document)

   ```
    FindReplaceOptions options = new FindReplaceOptions() { MatchCase = true };
    Document doc = new Document(@"C:\Git\source.docx");
    doc.Range.Replace("<var_Date>", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"), options);
    doc.Save(@"C:\Git\finalFile.docx");
   ```

   - Aspose requires a paid licence, but is comparatively faster to use on a server.